# I did it fast or quickly?

Tags: word-usage

I have read many books say that

> they ran fast.

But that sounds wrong compared to

> they ran quickly.

Which should it be?

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: There would often be a different nuance. For example, *She quickly ran to the shop to get some milk* would normally focus on the fact that getting the milk *didn't take long* (perhaps implying the shop is very close, and it's worth noting one can say this even if all she did was *walk* quickly). On the other hand, *She ran fast to the shop to get some milk* focuses more on the *high speed of her running* (though idiomatically it's not a very likely thing to say).

Comment: Are you asking why it is not "fastly"? 'cuz that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is fine (as is your second) even though "fast" looks like an adjective modifying a verb (adjectives, of course, can't normally modify verbs; only adverbs can do that, but read on).

English has several adjectives that have corresponding adverbs that don't take the -*ly* suffix. Words like "fast", "late" and "hard" can certainly be used either as adjectives or as adverbs, without the -*ly* (*she drove fast*; *let's arrive late*; *they tried hard.*

By all means use "quickly" if you wish, but don't do it because you think "fast" is wrong, because it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

**Quickly**. Adverb, modifies a verb. Not fast, an adjective that modifies a noun.